# Junior Dev Self-taught Resume Project

Tags: python, mysql

I've been learning Python now for 3 months as I find it really interesting to code. I want to be able to apply for junior dev positions and as I have no formal education I thought I'd make a project to feature what I know.

The project is still to be compeltely finsihed but it's got the meat of it done. I created a script to export data from a json file to automatically input to my MYSQL database. I've then used Pygame to create a periodic table GUI that enables you to press on a square (element ids and names yet to be added) and then it animates that atom with complete atom core configuration and electron shells. (Atom info on animation yet to be added) I'll provide the code below and some Images.

Do you guys think this is a good project to feature on a resume for my first junior dev position? Do you think this is a good project that shows I know what I'm doing? Do you think this could land me a job or do I need to show I know more?

Also, Is there a better way of saving each cell of the periodic table (to color and get data from while pressed) instead of making a list of them?

Here is some Images of GUI and Animation and thereafter the code used in the project:

[Period Table GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikzMk.png)

[Still Image of Atom Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVDhD.png)

JSON to MYSQL code:

```
import mysql.connector
import json
DB = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='OlijonDB', user='root', passwd='Testing123')
DBCursor = DB.cursor(prepared=True)

class Elements:
    def __init__(self, atomicnumber, symbol, name, atomicmass, type, electronconfig):
        self.atomicnumber = atomicnumber
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.name = name
        self.atomicmass = atomicmass
        self.type = type
        self.electronconfig = electronconfig

iteration = 0
with open('periodictable.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for elements in data:
        iteration += 1
        print(iteration)
        if elements['atomicNumber'] == iteration:
            try:
                atomicmass = elements['atomicMass'].split('.')
            except:
                atomicmass = elements['atomicMass']
            Element = Elements(elements['atomicNumber'], elements['symbol'], elements['name'], int(atomicmass[0]),
                               elements['groupBlock'], elements['electronicConfiguration'])
            SQLQuery = """ INSERT INTO elements
                               (atomicnumber, symbol, name, atomicmass, type, electronconfig) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) """
            Values = [Element.atomicnumber, Element.symbol, Element.name, Element.atomicmass, Element.type, Element.electronconfig]
            print(Element.atomicmass)
            DBCursor.execute(SQLQuery, Values)
            DB.commit()
```

Periodic Table Code:

```
import pygame
from AtomAnimation import *

def main():
    class Tables:
        def __init__(self):
            self.Dimensions = [25, 25, 1]
            self.Colors = [(255,255,255), (0,100,255), (255, 100, 0)]
            self.GridSize = 18
            self.Grid = []
            self.perodictable = [[4, 0], [4, 17], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 12], [5, 13], [5, 14], [5, 15], [5, 16], [5, 17],
                                 [6, 0], [6, 1], [6, 12], [6, 13], [6, 14], [6, 15], [6, 16], [6, 17], [7, 0], [7, 1],
                                 [7, 2], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9], [7, 10], [7, 11],
                                 [7, 12], [7, 13], [7, 14], [7, 15], [7, 16], [7, 17], [8, 0], [8, 1], [8, 2], [8, 3],
                                 [8, 4], [8, 5], [8, 6], [8, 7], [8, 8], [8, 9], [8, 10], [8, 11], [8, 12], [8, 13],
                                 [8, 14], [8, 15], [8, 16], [8, 17], [9, 0], [9, 1], [12, 2], [12, 3], [12, 4], [12, 5],
                                 [12, 6], [12, 7], [12, 8], [12, 9], [12, 10], [12, 11], [12, 12], [12, 13], [12, 14],
                                 [12, 15], [12, 16], [9, 3], [9, 4], [9, 5], [9, 6], [9, 7], [9, 8], [9, 9], [9, 10],
                                 [9, 11], [9, 12], [9, 13], [9, 14], [9, 15], [9, 16], [9, 17], [10, 0], [10, 1], [13, 2],
                                 [13, 3], [13, 4], [13, 5], [13, 6], [13, 7], [13, 8], [13, 9], [13, 10], [13, 11], [13, 12],
                                 [13, 13], [13, 14], [13, 15], [13, 16], [10, 3], [10, 4], [10, 5], [10, 6], [10, 7], [10, 8],
                                 [10, 9], [10, 10], [10, 11], [10, 12], [10, 13], [10, 14], [10, 15], [10, 16], [10, 17]]

        def GenerateGrid(self):
            for Row in range(self.GridSize):
                self.Grid.append([])
                for Column in range(self.GridSize):
                    self.Grid[Row].append(0)

            for i in range(len(self.perodictable)):
                self.Grid[self.perodictable[i][0]][self.perodictable[i][1]] = 1

    def Render():
        GameWindow.fill((255,255,255))
        for Row in range(Table.GridSize):
            for Column in range(Table.GridSize):
                if Table.Grid[Row][Column] == 0:
                    Color = Table.Colors[0]
                elif Table.Grid[Row][Column] == 1:
                    Color = Table.Colors[1]
                pygame.draw.rect(GameWindow, Color,
                                 [(Table.Dimensions[2] + Table.Dimensions[0]) * Column + Table.Dimensions[2],
                                  (Table.Dimensions[2] + Table.Dimensions[1]) * Row + Table.Dimensions[2],
                                  Table.Dimensions[0], Table.Dimensions[1]])
        pygame.display.update()

    Table = Tables()
    Table.GenerateGrid()
    pygame.init()
    GameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((468, 468))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Periodic Table")
    Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    Run = True
    while Run:
        Clock.tick(30)
        Events = pygame.event.get()
        for Event in Events:
            if Event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Run = False
            elif Event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                MousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                Column = MousePosition[0] // (Table.Dimensions[0] + Table.Dimensions[2])
                Row = MousePosition[1] // (Table.Dimensions[1] + Table.Dimensions[2])
                if Table.Grid[Row][Column] == 1:
                    SimulateAtom(int(Table.perodictable.index([Row, Column]) + 1))

        Render()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Atom Animation Code:

```
import mysql.connector
import pygame
import random
import math
import time

def SimulateAtom(condition):
    class Atoms:
        def __init__(self, Name, Protons, Neutrons, Electrons):
            self.Name = Name
            self.Protons = Protons
            self.Neutrons = Neutrons
            self.Electrons = Electrons
            self.CenterPosition = [500, 500]

        #Create & Render Atom Composition
        def GenerateAtom(self, AppWindow):
            #Atom Core
            for i in range(self.Protons + self.Neutrons):
                pygame.draw.circle(AppWindow, (random.randrange(100, 255), 0, random.randrange(100, 255)),
                                   [self.CenterPosition[0] + Randomize(0, 10), self.CenterPosition[1] + Randomize(0, 10)], 20)
            #Electron Shells
            for i in range(len(self.Electrons[0].split(","))):
                radius = [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400]
                pygame.draw.circle(AppWindow, (211, 211, 211), self.CenterPosition, radius[i], 2)
                for j in range(int(self.Electrons[0].split(",")[i])):
                    angle = random.randint(0, int((10 - 1) / 0.1)) * 0.1 + 1
                    pygame.draw.circle(AppWindow, [0,random.randrange(100, 255),random.randrange(100, 255)], [round(radius[i] * math.cos(angle) + self.CenterPosition[0]),
                                                  round(radius[i] * math.sin(angle) + self.CenterPosition[1])], 8)
                    pygame.draw.circle(AppWindow, (211,211,211), self.CenterPosition, radius[i], 2)

    #Randomized Position Function
    def Randomize(start, stop):
        if random.randrange(0, 2) == 1:
            return + random.randrange(start, stop)
        else:
            return - random.randrange(start, stop)

    #Rendering Loop
    def Render():
        AppWindow.fill((255, 255, 255))
        Atom.GenerateAtom(AppWindow)
        pygame.display.update()

    #Connect to Database
    DB = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='OlijonDB', user='root', passwd='Testing123')
    DBCursor = DB.cursor(prepared=True)
    DBCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM elements WHERE atomicnumber = %s", (condition,))
    result = DBCursor.fetchone()
    Atom = Atoms(result[3], result[1], result[4] - result[1], [result[6]])

    #Initiate Pygame
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Element: " + str(Atom.Name))
    AppWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
    Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #Main App Loop
    Run = True
    while Run:
        Clock.tick(30)
        Events = pygame.event.get()
        for Event in Events:
            if Event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Run = False

        time.sleep(0.3)
        pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
        Render()
    pygame.quit()
```

Periodictable JSON:

```
[
{"atomicNumber":1,"symbol":"H","name":"Hydrogen","atomicMass":"1.00794(4)","cpkHexColor":"FFFFFF","electronicConfiguration":"1","electronegativity":2.2,"atomicRadius":37,"ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":120,"ionizationEnergy":1312,"electronAffinity":-73,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1","standardState":"gas","bondingType":"diatomic","meltingPoint":14,"boilingPoint":20,"density":0.0000899,"groupBlock":"nonmetal","yearDiscovered":1766},
{"atomicNumber":2,"symbol":"He","name":"Helium","atomicMass":"4.002602(2)","cpkHexColor":"D9FFFF","electronicConfiguration":"2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":32,"ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":140,"ionizationEnergy":2372,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":"","standardState":"gas","bondingType":"atomic","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":4,"density":0.0001785,"groupBlock":"noble gas","yearDiscovered":1868},
{"atomicNumber":3,"symbol":"Li","name":"Lithium","atomicMass":"6.941(2)","cpkHexColor":"CC80FF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 1","electronegativity":0.98,"atomicRadius":134,"ionRadius":"76 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":182,"ionizationEnergy":520,"electronAffinity":-60,"oxidationStates":1,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":454,"boilingPoint":1615,"density":0.535,"groupBlock":"alkali metal","yearDiscovered":1817},
{"atomicNumber":4,"symbol":"Be","name":"Beryllium","atomicMass":"9.012182(3)","cpkHexColor":"C2FF00","electronicConfiguration":"2, 2","electronegativity":1.57,"atomicRadius":90,"ionRadius":"45 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":900,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":2,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1560,"boilingPoint":2743,"density":1.848,"groupBlock":"alkaline earth metal","yearDiscovered":1798},
{"atomicNumber":5,"symbol":"B","name":"Boron","atomicMass":"10.811(7)","cpkHexColor":"FFB5B5","electronicConfiguration":"2, 3","electronegativity":2.04,"atomicRadius":82,"ionRadius":"27 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":801,"electronAffinity":-27,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"covalent network","meltingPoint":2348,"boilingPoint":4273,"density":2.46,"groupBlock":"metalloid","yearDiscovered":1807},
{"atomicNumber":6,"symbol":"C","name":"Carbon","atomicMass":"12.0107(8)","cpkHexColor":909090,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 4","electronegativity":2.55,"atomicRadius":77,"ionRadius":"16 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":170,"ionizationEnergy":1087,"electronAffinity":-154,"oxidationStates":"-4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"covalent network","meltingPoint":3823,"boilingPoint":4300,"density":2.26,"groupBlock":"nonmetal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":7,"symbol":"N","name":"Nitrogen","atomicMass":"14.0067(2)","cpkHexColor":"3050F8","electronicConfiguration":"2, 5","electronegativity":3.04,"atomicRadius":75,"ionRadius":"146 (-3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":155,"ionizationEnergy":1402,"electronAffinity":-7,"oxidationStates":"-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5","standardState":"gas","bondingType":"diatomic","meltingPoint":63,"boilingPoint":77,"density":0.001251,"groupBlock":"nonmetal","yearDiscovered":1772},
{"atomicNumber":8,"symbol":"O","name":"Oxygen","atomicMass":"15.9994(3)","cpkHexColor":"FF0D0D","electronicConfiguration":"2, 6","electronegativity":3.44,"atomicRadius":73,"ionRadius":"140 (-2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":152,"ionizationEnergy":1314,"electronAffinity":-141,"oxidationStates":"-2, -1, 1, 2","standardState":"gas","bondingType":"diatomic","meltingPoint":55,"boilingPoint":90,"density":0.001429,"groupBlock":"nonmetal","yearDiscovered":1774},
{"atomicNumber":9,"symbol":"F","name":"Fluorine","atomicMass":"18.9984032(5)","cpkHexColor":9e+51,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 7","electronegativity":3.98,"atomicRadius":71,"ionRadius":"133 (-1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":147,"ionizationEnergy":1681,"electronAffinity":-328,"oxidationStates":-1,"standardState":"gas","bondingType":"atomic","meltingPoint":54,"boilingPoint":85,"density":0.001696,"groupBlock":"halogen","yearDiscovered":1670},
{"atomicNumber":10,"symbol":"Ne","name":"Neon","atomicMass":"20.1797(6)","cpkHexColor":"B3E3F5","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":69,"ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":154,"ionizationEnergy":2081,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":"","standardState":"gas","bondingType":"atomic","meltingPoint":25,"boilingPoint":27,"density":0.0009,"groupBlock":"noble gas","yearDiscovered":1898},
{"atomicNumber":11,"symbol":"Na","name":"Sodium","atomicMass":"22.98976928(2)","cpkHexColor":"AB5CF2","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 1","electronegativity":0.93,"atomicRadius":154,"ionRadius":"102 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":227,"ionizationEnergy":496,"electronAffinity":-53,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":371,"boilingPoint":1156,"density":0.968,"groupBlock":"alkali metal","yearDiscovered":1807},
{"atomicNumber":12,"symbol":"Mg","name":"Magnesium","atomicMass":"24.3050(6)","cpkHexColor":"8AFF00","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.31,"atomicRadius":130,"ionRadius":"72 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":173,"ionizationEnergy":738,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":"1, 2","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":923,"boilingPoint":1363,"density":1.738,"groupBlock":"alkaline earth metal","yearDiscovered":1808},
{"atomicNumber":13,"symbol":"Al","name":"Aluminum","atomicMass":"26.9815386(8)","cpkHexColor":"BFA6A6","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 3","electronegativity":1.61,"atomicRadius":118,"ionRadius":"53.5 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":578,"electronAffinity":-43,"oxidationStates":"1, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":933,"boilingPoint":2792,"density":2.7,"groupBlock":"metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":14,"symbol":"Si","name":"Silicon","atomicMass":"28.0855(3)","cpkHexColor":"F0C8A0","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 4","electronegativity":1.9,"atomicRadius":111,"ionRadius":"40 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":210,"ionizationEnergy":787,"electronAffinity":-134,"oxidationStates":"-4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1687,"boilingPoint":3173,"density":2.33,"groupBlock":"metalloid","yearDiscovered":1854},
{"atomicNumber":15,"symbol":"P","name":"Phosphorus","atomicMass":"30.973762(2)","cpkHexColor":"FF8000","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 5","electronegativity":2.19,"atomicRadius":106,"ionRadius":"44 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":180,"ionizationEnergy":1012,"electronAffinity":-72,"oxidationStates":"-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"covalent network","meltingPoint":317,"boilingPoint":554,"density":1.823,"groupBlock":"nonmetal","yearDiscovered":1669},
{"atomicNumber":16,"symbol":"S","name":"Sulfur","atomicMass":"32.065(5)","cpkHexColor":"FFFF30","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 6","electronegativity":2.58,"atomicRadius":102,"ionRadius":"184 (-2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":180,"ionizationEnergy":1000,"electronAffinity":-200,"oxidationStates":"-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"covalent network","meltingPoint":388,"boilingPoint":718,"density":1.96,"groupBlock":"nonmetal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":17,"symbol":"Cl","name":"Chlorine","atomicMass":"35.453(2)","cpkHexColor":"1FF01F","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 7","electronegativity":3.16,"atomicRadius":99,"ionRadius":"181 (-1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":175,"ionizationEnergy":1251,"electronAffinity":-349,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7","standardState":"gas","bondingType":"covalent network","meltingPoint":172,"boilingPoint":239,"density":0.003214,"groupBlock":"halogen","yearDiscovered":1774},
{"atomicNumber":18,"symbol":"Ar","name":"Argon","atomicMass":"39.948(1)","cpkHexColor":"80D1E3","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 8","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":97,"ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":188,"ionizationEnergy":1521,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":"","standardState":"gas","bondingType":"atomic","meltingPoint":84,"boilingPoint":87,"density":0.001784,"groupBlock":"noble gas","yearDiscovered":1894},
{"atomicNumber":19,"symbol":"K","name":"Potassium","atomicMass":"39.0983(1)","cpkHexColor":"8F40D4","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 8, 1","electronegativity":0.82,"atomicRadius":196,"ionRadius":"138 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":275,"ionizationEnergy":419,"electronAffinity":-48,"oxidationStates":1,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":337,"boilingPoint":1032,"density":0.856,"groupBlock":"alkali metal","yearDiscovered":1807},
{"atomicNumber":20,"symbol":"Ca","name":"Calcium","atomicMass":"40.078(4)","cpkHexColor":"3DFF00","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 8, 2","electronegativity":1,"atomicRadius":174,"ionRadius":"100 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":590,"electronAffinity":-2,"oxidationStates":2,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1115,"boilingPoint":1757,"density":1.55,"groupBlock":"alkaline earth metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":21,"symbol":"Sc","name":"Scandium","atomicMass":"44.955912(6)","cpkHexColor":"E6E6E6","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.36,"atomicRadius":144,"ionRadius":"74.5 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":633,"electronAffinity":-18,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1814,"boilingPoint":3103,"density":2.985,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1876},
{"atomicNumber":22,"symbol":"Ti","name":"Titanium","atomicMass":"47.867(1)","cpkHexColor":"BFC2C7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 10, 2","electronegativity":1.54,"atomicRadius":136,"ionRadius":"86 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":659,"electronAffinity":-8,"oxidationStates":"-1, 2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1941,"boilingPoint":3560,"density":4.507,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1791},
{"atomicNumber":23,"symbol":"V","name":"Vanadium","atomicMass":"50.9415(1)","cpkHexColor":"A6A6AB","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 11, 2","electronegativity":1.63,"atomicRadius":125,"ionRadius":"79 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":651,"electronAffinity":-51,"oxidationStates":"-1, 2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2183,"boilingPoint":3680,"density":6.11,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1803},
{"atomicNumber":24,"symbol":"Cr","name":"Chromium","atomicMass":"51.9961(6)","cpkHexColor":"8A99C7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 13, 1","electronegativity":1.66,"atomicRadius":127,"ionRadius":"80 (+2*)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":653,"electronAffinity":-64,"oxidationStates":"-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2180,"boilingPoint":2944,"density":7.14,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":25,"symbol":"Mn","name":"Manganese","atomicMass":"54.938045(5)","cpkHexColor":"9C7AC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 13, 2","electronegativity":1.55,"atomicRadius":139,"ionRadius":"67 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":717,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":"-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1519,"boilingPoint":2334,"density":7.47,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1774},
{"atomicNumber":26,"symbol":"Fe","name":"Iron","atomicMass":"55.845(2)","cpkHexColor":"E06633","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 14, 2","electronegativity":1.83,"atomicRadius":125,"ionRadius":"78 (+2*)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":763,"electronAffinity":-16,"oxidationStates":"-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1811,"boilingPoint":3134,"density":7.874,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":27,"symbol":"Co","name":"Cobalt","atomicMass":"58.933195(5)","cpkHexColor":"F090A0","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 15, 2","electronegativity":1.88,"atomicRadius":126,"ionRadius":"74.5 (+2*)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":760,"electronAffinity":-64,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1768,"boilingPoint":3200,"density":8.9,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":28,"symbol":"Ni","name":"Nickel","atomicMass":"58.6934(4)","cpkHexColor":"50D050","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 16, 2","electronegativity":1.91,"atomicRadius":121,"ionRadius":"69 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":163,"ionizationEnergy":737,"electronAffinity":-112,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1, 2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1728,"boilingPoint":3186,"density":8.908,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1751},
{"atomicNumber":29,"symbol":"Cu","name":"Copper","atomicMass":"63.546(3)","cpkHexColor":"C88033","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 1","electronegativity":1.9,"atomicRadius":138,"ionRadius":"77 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":140,"ionizationEnergy":746,"electronAffinity":-118,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1358,"boilingPoint":3200,"density":8.92,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":30,"symbol":"Zn","name":"Zinc","atomicMass":"65.38(2)","cpkHexColor":"7D80B0","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 2","electronegativity":1.65,"atomicRadius":131,"ionRadius":"74 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":139,"ionizationEnergy":906,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":2,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":693,"boilingPoint":1180,"density":7.14,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1746},
{"atomicNumber":31,"symbol":"Ga","name":"Gallium","atomicMass":"69.723(1)","cpkHexColor":"C28F8F","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 3","electronegativity":1.81,"atomicRadius":126,"ionRadius":"62 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":187,"ionizationEnergy":579,"electronAffinity":-29,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":303,"boilingPoint":2477,"density":5.904,"groupBlock":"metal","yearDiscovered":1875},
{"atomicNumber":32,"symbol":"Ge","name":"Germanium","atomicMass":"72.64(1)","cpkHexColor":"668F8F","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 4","electronegativity":2.01,"atomicRadius":122,"ionRadius":"73 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":762,"electronAffinity":-119,"oxidationStates":"-4, 1, 2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1211,"boilingPoint":3093,"density":5.323,"groupBlock":"metalloid","yearDiscovered":1886},
{"atomicNumber":33,"symbol":"As","name":"Arsenic","atomicMass":"74.92160(2)","cpkHexColor":"BD80E3","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 5","electronegativity":2.18,"atomicRadius":119,"ionRadius":"58 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":185,"ionizationEnergy":947,"electronAffinity":-78,"oxidationStates":"-3, 2, 3, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1090,"boilingPoint":887,"density":5.727,"groupBlock":"metalloid","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":34,"symbol":"Se","name":"Selenium","atomicMass":"78.96(3)","cpkHexColor":"FFA100","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 6","electronegativity":2.55,"atomicRadius":116,"ionRadius":"198 (-2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":190,"ionizationEnergy":941,"electronAffinity":-195,"oxidationStates":"-2, 2, 4, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":494,"boilingPoint":958,"density":4.819,"groupBlock":"nonmetal","yearDiscovered":1817},
{"atomicNumber":35,"symbol":"Br","name":"Bromine","atomicMass":"79.904(1)","cpkHexColor":"A62929","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 7","electronegativity":2.96,"atomicRadius":114,"ionRadius":"196 (-1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":185,"ionizationEnergy":1140,"electronAffinity":-325,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7","standardState":"liquid","bondingType":"covalent network","meltingPoint":266,"boilingPoint":332,"density":3.12,"groupBlock":"halogen","yearDiscovered":1826},
{"atomicNumber":36,"symbol":"Kr","name":"Krypton","atomicMass":"83.798(2)","cpkHexColor":"5CB8D1","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 8","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":110,"ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":202,"ionizationEnergy":1351,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":2,"standardState":"gas","bondingType":"atomic","meltingPoint":116,"boilingPoint":120,"density":0.00375,"groupBlock":"noble gas","yearDiscovered":1898},
{"atomicNumber":37,"symbol":"Rb","name":"Rubidium","atomicMass":"85.4678(3)","cpkHexColor":"702EB0","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 8, 1","electronegativity":0.82,"atomicRadius":211,"ionRadius":"152 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":403,"electronAffinity":-47,"oxidationStates":1,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":312,"boilingPoint":961,"density":1.532,"groupBlock":"alkali metal","yearDiscovered":1861},
{"atomicNumber":38,"symbol":"Sr","name":"Strontium","atomicMass":"87.62(1)","cpkHexColor":"00FF00","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 8, 2","electronegativity":0.95,"atomicRadius":192,"ionRadius":"118 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":550,"electronAffinity":-5,"oxidationStates":2,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1050,"boilingPoint":1655,"density":2.63,"groupBlock":"alkaline earth metal","yearDiscovered":1790},
{"atomicNumber":39,"symbol":"Y","name":"Yttrium","atomicMass":"88.90585(2)","cpkHexColor":"94FFFF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.22,"atomicRadius":162,"ionRadius":"90 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":600,"electronAffinity":-30,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1799,"boilingPoint":3618,"density":4.472,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1794},
{"atomicNumber":40,"symbol":"Zr","name":"Zirconium","atomicMass":"91.224(2)","cpkHexColor":"94E0E0","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 10, 2","electronegativity":1.33,"atomicRadius":148,"ionRadius":"72 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":640,"electronAffinity":-41,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2128,"boilingPoint":4682,"density":6.511,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1789},
{"atomicNumber":41,"symbol":"Nb","name":"Niobium","atomicMass":"92.90638(2)","cpkHexColor":"73C2C9","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 12, 1","electronegativity":1.6,"atomicRadius":137,"ionRadius":"72 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":652,"electronAffinity":-86,"oxidationStates":"-1, 2, 3, 4, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2750,"boilingPoint":5017,"density":8.57,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1801},
{"atomicNumber":42,"symbol":"Mo","name":"Molybdenum","atomicMass":"95.96(2)","cpkHexColor":"54B5B5","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 13, 1","electronegativity":2.16,"atomicRadius":145,"ionRadius":"69 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":684,"electronAffinity":-72,"oxidationStates":"-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2896,"boilingPoint":4912,"density":10.28,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1778},
{"atomicNumber":43,"symbol":"Tc","name":"Technetium","atomicMass":[98],"cpkHexColor":"3B9E9E","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 13, 2","electronegativity":1.9,"atomicRadius":156,"ionRadius":"64.5 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":702,"electronAffinity":-53,"oxidationStates":"-3, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2430,"boilingPoint":4538,"density":11.5,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1937},
{"atomicNumber":44,"symbol":"Ru","name":"Ruthenium","atomicMass":"101.07(2)","cpkHexColor":"248F8F","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 15, 1","electronegativity":2.2,"atomicRadius":126,"ionRadius":"68 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":710,"electronAffinity":-101,"oxidationStates":"-2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2607,"boilingPoint":4423,"density":12.37,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1827},
{"atomicNumber":45,"symbol":"Rh","name":"Rhodium","atomicMass":"102.90550(2)","cpkHexColor":"0A7D8C","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 16, 1","electronegativity":2.28,"atomicRadius":135,"ionRadius":"66.5 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":720,"electronAffinity":-110,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2237,"boilingPoint":3968,"density":12.45,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1803},
{"atomicNumber":46,"symbol":"Pd","name":"Palladium","atomicMass":"106.42(1)","cpkHexColor":6985,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18","electronegativity":2.2,"atomicRadius":131,"ionRadius":"59 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":163,"ionizationEnergy":804,"electronAffinity":-54,"oxidationStates":"2, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1828,"boilingPoint":3236,"density":12.023,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1803},
{"atomicNumber":47,"symbol":"Ag","name":"Silver","atomicMass":"107.8682(2)","cpkHexColor":"C0C0C0","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 1","electronegativity":1.93,"atomicRadius":153,"ionRadius":"115 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":172,"ionizationEnergy":731,"electronAffinity":-126,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1235,"boilingPoint":2435,"density":10.49,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":48,"symbol":"Cd","name":"Cadmium","atomicMass":"112.411(8)","cpkHexColor":"FFD98F","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 2","electronegativity":1.69,"atomicRadius":148,"ionRadius":"95 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":158,"ionizationEnergy":868,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":2,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":594,"boilingPoint":1040,"density":8.65,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1817},
{"atomicNumber":49,"symbol":"In","name":"Indium","atomicMass":"114.818(3)","cpkHexColor":"A67573","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 3","electronegativity":1.78,"atomicRadius":144,"ionRadius":"80 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":193,"ionizationEnergy":558,"electronAffinity":-29,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":430,"boilingPoint":2345,"density":7.31,"groupBlock":"metal","yearDiscovered":1863},
{"atomicNumber":50,"symbol":"Sn","name":"Tin","atomicMass":"118.710(7)","cpkHexColor":668080,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 4","electronegativity":1.96,"atomicRadius":141,"ionRadius":"112 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":217,"ionizationEnergy":709,"electronAffinity":-107,"oxidationStates":"-4, 2, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":505,"boilingPoint":2875,"density":7.31,"groupBlock":"metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":51,"symbol":"Sb","name":"Antimony","atomicMass":"121.760(1)","cpkHexColor":"9E63B5","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 5","electronegativity":2.05,"atomicRadius":138,"ionRadius":"76 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":834,"electronAffinity":-103,"oxidationStates":"-3, 3, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":904,"boilingPoint":1860,"density":6.697,"groupBlock":"metalloid","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":52,"symbol":"Te","name":"Tellurium","atomicMass":"127.60(3)","cpkHexColor":"D47A00","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 6","electronegativity":2.1,"atomicRadius":135,"ionRadius":"221 (-2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":206,"ionizationEnergy":869,"electronAffinity":-190,"oxidationStates":"-2, 2, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":723,"boilingPoint":1261,"density":6.24,"groupBlock":"metalloid","yearDiscovered":1782},
{"atomicNumber":53,"symbol":"I","name":"Iodine","atomicMass":"126.90447(3)","cpkHexColor":940094,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 7","electronegativity":2.66,"atomicRadius":133,"ionRadius":"220 (-1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":198,"ionizationEnergy":1008,"electronAffinity":-295,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1, 3, 5, 7","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"covalent network","meltingPoint":387,"boilingPoint":457,"density":4.94,"groupBlock":"halogen","yearDiscovered":1811},
{"atomicNumber":54,"symbol":"Xe","name":"Xenon","atomicMass":"131.293(6)","cpkHexColor":"429EB0","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 8","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":130,"ionRadius":"48 (+8)","vanDerWaalsRadius":216,"ionizationEnergy":1170,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":"2, 4, 6, 8","standardState":"gas","bondingType":"atomic","meltingPoint":161,"boilingPoint":165,"density":0.0059,"groupBlock":"noble gas","yearDiscovered":1898},
{"atomicNumber":55,"symbol":"Cs","name":"Cesium","atomicMass":"132.9054519(2)","cpkHexColor":"57178F","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 8, 1","electronegativity":0.79,"atomicRadius":225,"ionRadius":"167 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":376,"electronAffinity":-46,"oxidationStates":1,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":302,"boilingPoint":944,"density":1.879,"groupBlock":"alkali metal","yearDiscovered":1860},
{"atomicNumber":56,"symbol":"Ba","name":"Barium","atomicMass":"137.327(7)","cpkHexColor":"00C900","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 8, 2","electronegativity":0.89,"atomicRadius":198,"ionRadius":"135 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":503,"electronAffinity":-14,"oxidationStates":2,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1000,"boilingPoint":2143,"density":3.51,"groupBlock":"alkaline earth metal","yearDiscovered":1808},
{"atomicNumber":57,"symbol":"La","name":"Lanthanum","atomicMass":"138.90547(7)","cpkHexColor":"70D4FF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 18, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.1,"atomicRadius":169,"ionRadius":"103.2 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":538,"electronAffinity":-48,"oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1193,"boilingPoint":3737,"density":6.146,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1839},
{"atomicNumber":58,"symbol":"Ce","name":"Cerium","atomicMass":"140.116(1)","cpkHexColor":"FFFFC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 19, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.12,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"102 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":534,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1071,"boilingPoint":3633,"density":6.689,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1803},
{"atomicNumber":59,"symbol":"Pr","name":"Praseodymium","atomicMass":"140.90765(2)","cpkHexColor":"D9FFC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 21, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.13,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"99 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":527,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1204,"boilingPoint":3563,"density":6.64,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1885},
{"atomicNumber":60,"symbol":"Nd","name":"Neodymium","atomicMass":"144.242(3)","cpkHexColor":"C7FFC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 22, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.14,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"129 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":533,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1294,"boilingPoint":3373,"density":7.01,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1885},
{"atomicNumber":61,"symbol":"Pm","name":"Promethium","atomicMass":[145],"cpkHexColor":"A3FFC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 23, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.13,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"97 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":540,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":3,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1373,"boilingPoint":3273,"density":7.264,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1947},
{"atomicNumber":62,"symbol":"Sm","name":"Samarium","atomicMass":"150.36(2)","cpkHexColor":"8FFFC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 24, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.17,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"122 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":545,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1345,"boilingPoint":2076,"density":7.353,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1853},
{"atomicNumber":63,"symbol":"Eu","name":"Europium","atomicMass":"151.964(1)","cpkHexColor":"61FFC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 25, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.2,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"117 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":547,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint ":1095,"boilingPoint":1800,"density":5.244,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1901},
{"atomicNumber":64,"symbol":"Gd","name":"Gadolinium","atomicMass":"157.25(3)","cpkHexColor":"45FFC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 25, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.2,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"93.8 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":593,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1586,"boilingPoint":3523,"density":7.901,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1880},
{"atomicNumber":65,"symbol":"Tb","name":"Terbium","atomicMass":"158.92535(2)","cpkHexColor":"30FFC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 27, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.2,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"92.3 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":566,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"1, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1629,"boilingPoint":3503,"density":8.219,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1843},
{"atomicNumber":66,"symbol":"Dy","name":"Dysprosium","atomicMass":"162.500(1)","cpkHexColor":"1FFFC7","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 28, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.22,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"107 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":573,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1685,"boilingPoint":2840,"density":8.551,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1886},
{"atomicNumber":67,"symbol":"Ho","name":"Holmium","atomicMass":"164.93032(2)","cpkHexColor":"00FF9C","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 29, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.23,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"90.1 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":581,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":3,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1747,"boilingPoint":2973,"density":8.795,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1878},
{"atomicNumber":68,"symbol":"Er","name":"Erbium","atomicMass":"167.259(3)","cpkHexColor":0,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 30, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.24,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"89 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":589,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":3,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1770,"boilingPoint":3141,"density":9.066,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1842},
{"atomicNumber":69,"symbol":"Tm","name":"Thulium","atomicMass":"168.93421(2)","cpkHexColor":"00D452","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 31, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.25,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"103 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":597,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1818,"boilingPoint":2223,"density":9.321,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1879},
{"atomicNumber":70,"symbol":"Yb","name":"Ytterbium","atomicMass":"173.054(5)","cpkHexColor":"00BF38","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.1,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"102 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":603,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1092,"boilingPoint":1469,"density":6.57,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1878},
{"atomicNumber":71,"symbol":"Lu","name":"Lutetium","atomicMass":"174.9668(1)","cpkHexColor":"00AB24","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.27,"atomicRadius":160,"ionRadius":"86.1 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":524,"electronAffinity":-50,"oxidationStates":3,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1936,"boilingPoint":3675,"density":9.841,"groupBlock":"lanthanoid","yearDiscovered":1907},
{"atomicNumber":72,"symbol":"Hf","name":"Hafnium","atomicMass":"178.49(2)","cpkHexColor":"4DC2FF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 10, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":150,"ionRadius":"71 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":659,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":"2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2506,"boilingPoint":4876,"density":13.31,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1923},
{"atomicNumber":73,"symbol":"Ta","name":"Tantalum","atomicMass":"180.94788(2)","cpkHexColor":"4DA6FF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 11, 2","electronegativity":1.5,"atomicRadius":138,"ionRadius":"72 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":761,"electronAffinity":-31,"oxidationStates":"-1, 2, 3, 4, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":3290,"boilingPoint":5731,"density":16.65,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1802},
{"atomicNumber":74,"symbol":"W","name":"Tungsten","atomicMass":"183.84(1)","cpkHexColor":"2194D6","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 12, 2","electronegativity":2.36,"atomicRadius":146,"ionRadius":"66 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":770,"electronAffinity":-79,"oxidationStates":"-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":3695,"boilingPoint":5828,"density":19.25,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1783},
{"atomicNumber":75,"symbol":"Re","name":"Rhenium","atomicMass":"186.207(1)","cpkHexColor":"267DAB","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 13, 2","electronegativity":1.9,"atomicRadius":159,"ionRadius":"63 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":760,"electronAffinity":-15,"oxidationStates":"-3, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":3459,"boilingPoint":5869,"density":21.02,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1925},
{"atomicNumber":76,"symbol":"Os","name":"Osmium","atomicMass":"190.23(3)","cpkHexColor":266696,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 14, 2","electronegativity":2.2,"atomicRadius":128,"ionRadius":"63 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":840,"electronAffinity":-106,"oxidationStates":"-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":3306,"boilingPoint":5285,"density":22.61,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1803},
{"atomicNumber":77,"symbol":"Ir","name":"Iridium","atomicMass":"192.217(3)","cpkHexColor":175487,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 15, 2","electronegativity":2.2,"atomicRadius":137,"ionRadius":"68 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":880,"electronAffinity":-151,"oxidationStates":"-3, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2739,"boilingPoint":4701,"density":22.65,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1803},
{"atomicNumber":78,"symbol":"Pt","name":"Platinum","atomicMass":"195.084(9)","cpkHexColor":"D0D0E0","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 17, 1","electronegativity":2.28,"atomicRadius":128,"ionRadius":"86 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":175,"ionizationEnergy":870,"electronAffinity":-205,"oxidationStates":"2, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2041,"boilingPoint":4098,"density":21.09,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":79,"symbol":"Au","name":"Gold","atomicMass":"196.966569(4)","cpkHexColor":"FFD123","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 1","electronegativity":2.54,"atomicRadius":144,"ionRadius":"137 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":166,"ionizationEnergy":890,"electronAffinity":-223,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1, 2, 3, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1337,"boilingPoint":3129,"density":19.3,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":80,"symbol":"Hg","name":"Mercury","atomicMass":"200.59(2)","cpkHexColor":"B8B8D0","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 2","electronegativity":2,"atomicRadius":149,"ionRadius":"119 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":155,"ionizationEnergy":1007,"electronAffinity":0,"oxidationStates":"1, 2, 4","standardState":"liquid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":234,"boilingPoint":630,"density":13.534,"groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":81,"symbol":"Tl","name":"Thallium","atomicMass":"204.3833(2)","cpkHexColor":"A6544D","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 3","electronegativity":2.04,"atomicRadius":148,"ionRadius":"150 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":196,"ionizationEnergy":589,"electronAffinity":-19,"oxidationStates":"1, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":577,"boilingPoint":1746,"density":11.85,"groupBlock":"metal","yearDiscovered":1861},
{"atomicNumber":82,"symbol":"Pb","name":"Lead","atomicMass":"207.2(1)","cpkHexColor":575961,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 4","electronegativity":2.33,"atomicRadius":147,"ionRadius":"119 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":202,"ionizationEnergy":716,"electronAffinity":-35,"oxidationStates":"-4, 2, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":601,"boilingPoint":2022,"density":11.34,"groupBlock":"metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":83,"symbol":"Bi","name":"Bismuth","atomicMass":"208.98040(1)","cpkHexColor":"9E4FB5","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 5","electronegativity":2.02,"atomicRadius":146,"ionRadius":"103 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":703,"electronAffinity":-91,"oxidationStates":"-3, 3, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":544,"boilingPoint":1837,"density":9.78,"groupBlock":"metal","yearDiscovered":"Ancient"},
{"atomicNumber":84,"symbol":"Po","name":"Polonium","atomicMass":[209],"cpkHexColor":"AB5C00","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 6","electronegativity":2,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"94 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":812,"electronAffinity":-183,"oxidationStates":"-2, 2, 4, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":527,"boilingPoint":1235,"density":9.196,"groupBlock":"metalloid","yearDiscovered":1898},
{"atomicNumber":85,"symbol":"At","name":"Astatine","atomicMass":[210],"cpkHexColor":"754F45","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 7","electronegativity":2.2,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"62 (+7)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":920,"electronAffinity":-270,"oxidationStates":"-1, 1, 3, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"covalent network","meltingPoint":575,"boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"halogen","yearDiscovered":1940},
{"atomicNumber":86,"symbol":"Rn","name":"Radon","atomicMass":[222],"cpkHexColor":428296,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 8","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":145,"ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":1037,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":2,"standardState":"gas","bondingType":"atomic","meltingPoint":202,"boilingPoint":211,"density":0.00973,"groupBlock":"noble gas","yearDiscovered":1900},
{"atomicNumber":87,"symbol":"Fr","name":"Francium","atomicMass":[223],"cpkHexColor":420066,"electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 8, 1","electronegativity":0.7,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"180 (+1)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":380,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":1,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"alkali metal","yearDiscovered":1939},
{"atomicNumber":88,"symbol":"Ra","name":"Radium","atomicMass":[226],"cpkHexColor":"007D00","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 8, 2","electronegativity":0.9,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"148 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":509,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":2,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":973,"boilingPoint":2010,"density":5,"groupBlock":"alkaline earth metal","yearDiscovered":1898},
{"atomicNumber":89,"symbol":"Ac","name":"Actinium","atomicMass":[227],"cpkHexColor":"70ABFA","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.1,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"112 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":499,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":3,"standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1323,"boilingPoint":3473,"density":10.07,"groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1899},
{"atomicNumber":90,"symbol":"Th","name":"Thorium","atomicMass":"232.03806(2)","cpkHexColor":"00BAFF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 18, 10, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"94 (+4)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":587,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":2023,"boilingPoint":5093,"density":11.724,"groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1828},
{"atomicNumber":91,"symbol":"Pa","name":"Protactinium","atomicMass":"231.03588(2)","cpkHexColor":"00A1FF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 20, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.5,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"104 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":568,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"3, 4, 5","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1845,"boilingPoint":4273,"density":15.37,"groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1913},
{"atomicNumber":92,"symbol":"U","name":"Uranium","atomicMass":"238.02891(3)","cpkHexColor":"008FFF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 21, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.38,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"102.5 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":186,"ionizationEnergy":598,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"3, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1408,"boilingPoint":4200,"density":19.05,"groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1789},
{"atomicNumber":93,"symbol":"Np","name":"Neptunium","atomicMass":[237],"cpkHexColor":"0080FF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 22, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.36,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"110 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":605,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"3, 4, 5, 6, 7","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":917,"boilingPoint":4273,"density":20.45,"groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1940},
{"atomicNumber":94,"symbol":"Pu","name":"Plutonium","atomicMass":[244],"cpkHexColor":"006BFF","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 24, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.28,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"100 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":585,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"3, 4, 5, 6, 7","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":913,"boilingPoint":3503,"density":19.816,"groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1940},
{"atomicNumber":95,"symbol":"Am","name":"Americium","atomicMass":[243],"cpkHexColor":"545CF2","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 25, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"126 (+2)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":578,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"2, 3, 4, 5, 6","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1449,"boilingPoint":2284,"density":"","groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1944},
{"atomicNumber":96,"symbol":"Cm","name":"Curium","atomicMass":[247],"cpkHexColor":"785CE3","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 25, 9, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"97 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":581,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1618,"boilingPoint":3383,"density":13.51,"groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1944},
{"atomicNumber":97,"symbol":"Bk","name":"Berkelium","atomicMass":[247],"cpkHexColor":"8A4FE3","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 27, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"96 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":601,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1323,"boilingPoint":"","density":14.78,"groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1949},
{"atomicNumber":98,"symbol":"Cf","name":"Californium","atomicMass":[251],"cpkHexColor":"A136D4","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 28, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"95 (+3)","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":608,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"2, 3, 4","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"metallic","meltingPoint":1173,"boilingPoint":"","density":15.1,"groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1950},
{"atomicNumber":99,"symbol":"Es","name":"Einsteinium","atomicMass":[252],"cpkHexColor":"B31FD4","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 29, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":619,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"solid","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":1133,"boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1952},
{"atomicNumber":100,"symbol":"Fm","name":"Fermium","atomicMass":[257],"cpkHexColor":"B31FBA","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 30, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":627,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":1800,"boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1952},
{"atomicNumber":101,"symbol":"Md","name":"Mendelevium","atomicMass":[258],"cpkHexColor":"B30DA6","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 31, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":635,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":1100,"boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1955},
{"atomicNumber":102,"symbol":"No","name":"Nobelium","atomicMass":[259],"cpkHexColor":"BD0D87","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 8, 2","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":642,"electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"2, 3","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":1100,"boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"actinoid","yearDiscovered":1957},
{"atomicNumber":103,"symbol":"Lr","name":"Lawrencium","atomicMass":[262],"cpkHexColor":"C70066","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 8, 3","electronegativity":1.3,"atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":3,"standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":1900,"boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1961},
{"atomicNumber":104,"symbol":"Rf","name":"Rutherfordium","atomicMass":[267],"cpkHexColor":"CC0059","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 10, 2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":4,"standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1969},
{"atomicNumber":105,"symbol":"Db","name":"Dubnium","atomicMass":[268],"cpkHexColor":"D1004F","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 11, 2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1967},
{"atomicNumber":106,"symbol":"Sg","name":"Seaborgium","atomicMass":[271],"cpkHexColor":"D90045","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 12, 2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1974},
{"atomicNumber":107,"symbol":"Bh","name":"Bohrium","atomicMass":[272],"cpkHexColor":"E00038","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 13, 2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1976},
{"atomicNumber":108,"symbol":"Hs","name":"Hassium","atomicMass":[270],"cpkHexColor":"E6002E","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 14, 2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1984},
{"atomicNumber":109,"symbol":"Mt","name":"Meitnerium","atomicMass":[276],"cpkHexColor":"EB0026","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 15, 2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1982},
{"atomicNumber":110,"symbol":"Ds","name":"Darmstadtium","atomicMass":[281],"cpkHexColor":"","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 16, 2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1994},
{"atomicNumber":111,"symbol":"Rg","name":"Roentgenium","atomicMass":[280],"cpkHexColor":"","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 17, 2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1994},
{"atomicNumber":112,"symbol":"Cn","name":"Copernicium","atomicMass":[285],"cpkHexColor":"","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 2","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"transition metal","yearDiscovered":1996},
{"atomicNumber":113,"symbol":"Nh","name":"Nihonium","atomicMass":[284],"cpkHexColor":"","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 3","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"post-transition metal","yearDiscovered":2003},
{"atomicNumber":114,"symbol":"Fl","name":"Flerovium","atomicMass":[289],"cpkHexColor":"","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 4","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"post-transition metal","yearDiscovered":1998},
{"atomicNumber":115,"symbol":"Mc","name":"Moscovium","atomicMass":[288],"cpkHexColor":"","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 5","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"post-transition metal","yearDiscovered":2003},
{"atomicNumber":116,"symbol":"Lv","name":"Livermorium","atomicMass":[293],"cpkHexColor":"","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 6","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"post-transition metal","yearDiscovered":2000},
{"atomicNumber":117,"symbol":"Ts","name":"Tennessine","atomicMass":[294],"cpkHexColor":"","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 7","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"post-transition metal","yearDiscovered":2010},
{"atomicNumber":118,"symbol":"Og","name":"Oganesson","atomicMass":[294],"cpkHexColor":"","electronicConfiguration":"2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 8","electronegativity":"","atomicRadius":"","ionRadius":"","vanDerWaalsRadius":"","ionizationEnergy":"","electronAffinity":"","oxidationStates":"","standardState":"","bondingType":"","meltingPoint":"","boilingPoint":"","density":"","groupBlock":"noble gas","yearDiscovered":2002}
]
```

Comment: Welcome! Good to see you are learning python programming :) But threse questions: "Do you guys think this is a good project to feature on a resume for my first junior dev position? Do you think this is a good project that shows I know what I'm doing? Do you think this could land me a job or do I need to show I know more?" --> are off topic for Code Review :)

Comment: @RobAu I asked it over att Stackoverflow first and they told me to post it here instead. Do you have any idea where I should post it?

Comment: We can review your code, no problem. But whether or not this project will land you a job is such a complicated question (depending on a lot of variables *and* outside of our scope) I wouldn't know where you'd get a decent answer on it. Please see our [help/on-topic] to see what we do and don't do here.

Comment: What does your `periodictable.json` look like? Why do you need `self.perodictable` on top of that?

Comment: At first glance, I think you could use some more practice before applying for a junior dev position. But if you provide us with more context about the code, we can probably review it in such a way to get you a decent start on your journey. You'll get there, but I wouldn't want this code-quality in my code base at work.

Comment: (Depending on mood, I might be put off by typos as in `compeltely finsihed`, `perodictable`, even lower-case acronyms.)

Comment: [Let the title state the goal of the code presented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mast Do you think you could help me out on how to improve my code-quality? What do I need to think about while writing?

Comment: If you put in the effort, I'm sure we can help you. I'm a bit short on time though, so if nobody else writes an answer it might take a while till I've finished mine. But your question does look interesting so I'll keep commenting till it's reviewable or answered. Please heed all comments that have been posted so far.